# socket.getaddrinfo failed error

Tags: python, sockets

I am getting socket.getaddrinfo error when I try to use urlib and socket modules.
So, I read some posts on SO and found everyone giving the solution to change the HTTP_PROXY. So, then I made the changes to my env. variable and now I can open:

```
import urllib, urllib2, httplib
url = 'http://www.google.com'
print "urllib"
data = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

But, if I try to use socket.addrinfo(host,port) I am still getting this error:

```
sockt.gaierror: [Errno 11004] Failed
```

I am trying to use the splunk SDK which makes a call to socket class and uses socket.getaddrinfo() function while setting up the connection. Does anyone know the solution for it?

Comment: Might have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180720/how-to-fix-socket-gaierror-11004-getaddrinfo-failed-error-in-gae).

Comment: Note that urllib has been deprecated. use urllib2.urlopen(url) instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441279/i-am-getting-error-socket-gaierror-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed says that an error in the host file could cause this problem.

Comment: Yes, I know about urlib. I was just giving the example that after setting up the http_proxy I was able to make it work. But I am not able to use socket.getaddrinfo(). I am actually using Splunk sdk which calls socket class to make the connection.